# binding navigator windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am a starter on windows forms and using binding navigator to perform CRUD operations on database records of a table.

I have binding navigator in place, which is bound to a datatable from code behind and all the controls on form(few textboxes and dropdown) are assigned databindings in code behind as well.

The problem:
I need an additional search functionality on one of textboxes where I can search text typed in the textbox in binding source and then show appropriate record to user.

The issue here is , as databindings of a textbox are working two way.the text typed in the textbox is reflected in the binding source datatable.

The search is going wrong as the source in which I am searching is no longer the original source but gets updated by values typed in that search textbox always..

This has probably become long.. and not a lot of code to attach..any suggestions on this welcome

Comment: Why the search TextBox need to be databind?

Comment: the value of it is coming from the database on first load as well...for example if I have record with name "test1","test2","test3" in database.
On first load "test1" is shown , but user can type "test2" in same textbox and press search and then it goes wrong..how can i do it otherwise?

Comment: Then you shall probably edit the databinding property, setting DataSourceUpdateMode to Never https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode(v=vs.110).aspx